# Writing multiple Rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

I've written two Rspec tests each which invoke the same Rake task.  The second task never gets run, as invoke only triggers once so I need to reenable.  My issue is that I can't get the rake task to run, here is the command I'm using:

```
Rake::Task["product:delete"].reenable(product.id)
```

I get a run time error for this command:

Don't know how to build task 'product:delete[1]' Did you mean? product:delete

Anybody know how I should write this?  I'm confused because in isolation I get it to pass by running:

```
Rake.application.invoke_task("product:delete[#{product.id}]"
```

Comment: Show us error text also.

Comment: Edited to add error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass an argument to [`reenable`](https://ruby.github.io/rake/Rake/Task.html#method-i-reenable) (it doesn't take one)

You should however be passing your argument to [`invoke`](https://ruby.github.io/rake/Rake/Task.html#method-i-invoke) (not invoke_task) rather than specifying it as part of the task name.

E.g.

```
Rake::Task['product:delete'].reenable
Rake::Task['product:delete'].invoke(product.id)
```

You could streamline it a little more perhaps by saving the task in a variable:

```
t = Rake::Task['product:delete']
t.renable
t.invoke(product.id)
```

P.S. It looks a lot like that error "Don't know how to build task 'product:delete[1]' Did you mean? product:delete" has actually come from you trying to invoke the task with the argument in the task name rather than from the reenable. Possibly as a result of trying a lot of different things.

Comment: Thanks Shadwell that did it.  Really appreciate the explanation, I'm much clearer on this now.